# retrieving items from a listbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, listbox, alert

I ma trying to retrieve the options selected from a listbox using jQuery. Here is the code.

```
$('#rt_select').click(function(e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#source-listbox option:selected');

}
```

I know that selectedOpts is an object so how to fetch the values of the options selected from this Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this,

```
   str = "";
   $.each(selectedOpts, function (index, value) {
    str += value+" ";
   });
   alert(str);
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use .val() to get the selected values

```
var selectedOpts = $('#source-listbox').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

To select the value, write this:

```
var val = selectedOpts.val();
```

or directly call

```
var val = $('#source-listbox').val();
```

**Update: selecting multiple options**

```
var values = [];
var selectedOpts = $('#source-listbox option:selected');
for (var x in selectedOpts) {
   values.push($(selectedOpts[x]).val());
}
alert(values);  //contains all values
```

Comment: This works fine. But what if I have selected multiple options ? The solution that you have given retrieves only the first option.

Comment: I get the following error TypeError: selectedOpts[x].val is not a function

Comment: Try `$(selectedOpts[x]).val()`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#rt_select').click(function(e) {
  // will give you selected options separated by (,)
  var option = $('#source-listbox').val();
  alert(option);
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wCu5y/

Answer (score 1):

Try **$.map()** to get all selected items in list

```
var selectedValues = $.map($('#ddlList option:selected'), function (element) {
        return eelement.value;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#demo").live("click", function () {
        //Get selected option of the HTML SELECT
        var selectedItem = $("#mySelect option:selected").last();
 
        //Get the value of the selected option
        alert("SelectedItem Value: " + selectedItem.val());
 
        //Get html or text of the selected option
        alert("SelectedItem Text: " + selectedItem.html());
 
        //Get index of selected option
        alert("SelectedItem Index: " + selectedItem.index());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasListItems = $('#ddlListItems option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.text).join();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.